# Почему event с клавиатуры является unknown при нажатии на клавишу

Tags: python, python-3.x, клавиатура, keyboardhook

Отслеживаю нажатия на клавиши клавиатуры и пишу их в лог. На окнах все нормально, но на убунту, используя модуль keyboard, при нажатии на обычные клавиши (q, w, e, r, t, y и т.д.)  он выдает unknown. Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*На скриншоте видно, что когда нажимаешь на цифры или esc, enter и т.д., то они выводятся. Когда нажимаю на обычные клавиши выпадает unknown

Comment: Выкладывайте, пожалуйста код _текстом_, а не картинкой!

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия3-8 какая разница в каком виде код в данном случае?

Comment: @Game Up  1. Его нельзя проверить (выполнить). 2. Его нельзя копировать при создания ответы (чтобы исправить ошибку) 

И ещё много-много причин

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия3-8 здесь дело не в коде

Answer (score -1):

Для работы с библиотекой keyboard в Linux требуются права root.

```
sudo python3 test.py
```

Comment: слева пример запуска. Без sudo не выполнить скрипт